# How does uniswap get the balance of eth or erc20 tokens?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, uniswap

How does uniswap get the balance of eth or erc20 tokens? I can't find in the interface code with the multicall contract.

Answer (score 1):

Uniswap versions before V3 used the default `balanceOf()` function which is a core function of the ERC20 standard

This changed in UniV3,I believe mostly to save gas

```
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = token0.staticcall(abi.encodeWithSelector(IERC20Minimal.balanceOf.selector, address(this)));
        require(success && data.length >= 32);
        return abi.decode(data, (uint256));
    }

    /// @dev Get the pool's balance of token1
    /// @dev This function is gas optimized to avoid a redundant extcodesize check in addition to the returndatasize
    /// check
    function balance1() private view returns (uint256) {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) =
            token1.staticcall(abi.encodeWithSelector(IERC20Minimal.balanceOf.selector, address(this)));
        require(success && data.length >= 32);
        return abi.decode(data, (uint256));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every ERC20 token has a mapping to keep track of balances of addresses

```
mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;
```

When Uniswap needs to check any balance of tokens, for example as in [UniswapV2Pair.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol), it first needs to get the address of deployed tokens and then checks the mapping inside of each contract

```
    // token0 is the contract address of token0
    uint balance0 = IERC20(token0).balanceOf(address(this));
    // token1 is the contract address of token1
    uint balance1 = IERC20(token1).balanceOf(address(this));
```